# Dual boot, 4 disks, raid0

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-8.1, raid

I have windows 8.1, and ubuntu 14.04 on the Disk 0. On ubuntu the four disks are merged. on windows i want to merge disks 1,2,3 (the windows half). but when i click to new striped volume, it says "there is not enough space on the disks to complete this operation.". someone to help?

note: 306.51 is ubuntu part.

[[image: Screenshot](click to enlarge)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqJjx.png)